# WPF&MVVM: как определить метод SetProperty для ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как определить метод `SetProperty` для `ViewModel` в шаблоне `MVVM`? Я видел в некоторых примерах, что для этого применяется интерфейс `BindingBase`, который тоже надо определять.

Мне нужно также определить `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Не сказать, что понимаю, но знаю, как это сделать. Видел в примерах, что от этого класса наследуют `ViewModel`, а иногда имплементируют в `BindingBase` (я сам запутался, так что не стоит слишком вникать в смысл этого предложения).

В данном примере необходим интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы был доступен метод `OnPropertyChanged()`, а также ещё какой-то интерфейс, чтобы выполнялся метод `SetProperty()`:

```
public class MyCalendar : BaseViewModel {

    // ... 

    private string _DayName;
    public string DayName {

        get { return _DayName; }
        set {
            _DayName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDay");
        }
    }

    private bool _IsWorkday;
    public bool IsWorkday {

        get { return _IsWorkday; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _IsWorkday, value); }

    }
}
```

Что следует добавить в класс `BaseViewModel`, чтобы в классе `MyCalendar` работал метод `SetProperty()`?

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "") {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас снова за ответ! Не хотелось бы тупо копипасить код без понимания; скажите, почему `OnPropertyChanged` больше не нужен?

Comment: Нужен, просто у меня он называется по другому: NotifyPropertyChanged